# MySQL Query - SELECT DISTINCT... (WHERE) issue

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Struggling with this MySQL query. When I take out the WHERE clause all the results appear for the user. So it isn't the php output that is the issue. I'm pretty sure it's in the WHERE clause, but I've been stuck for ages and can't work it out.

```
$test = $db->query
("SELECT DISTINCT(a.id), a.name 
FROM test AS a LEFT JOIN(testusers AS b,testclasses AS c, userclasses AS d)
ON (c.classID = d.classID AND a.id = b.testID)
WHERE d.userID='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "' OR b.userID= '" . $_SESSION["id"] . "' 
GROUP BY a.id");
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not reference columns from a LEFT JOINed table (e.g., `b.userID`) in the WHERE clause. When you do, you implicitly turn your JOIN into an INNER JOIN. Make those tests part of the JOIN condition instead.

DON'T do this:

```
/* Wrong */
SELECT *
    FROM test a
        LEFT JOIN test2users b
            ON a.id = b.testid
    WHERE b.userID = 123
```

DO this instead:

```
/* Right */
SELECT *
    FROM test a
        LEFT JOIN test2users b
            ON a.id = b.testid
                AND b.userID = 123
```

Answer (score 1):

I've cleaned up the join statements and removed the unnecessary DISTINCT(). What does this give you?

```
SELECT a.id, a.name 
FROM " . $config["table_prefix"] . "test AS a
LEFT JOIN " . $config["table_prefix"] . "test2users AS b
    ON a.id = b.testID
    AND b.userID= '" . $_SESSION["id"] . "' 
LEFT JOIN " . $config["table_prefix"] . "test2classes AS c
LEFT JOIN " . $config["table_prefix"] . "test2classes AS d
    ON c.classID = d.classID
    AND d.userID='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: this solution also works, however, I used Joe's as it is consistent with the rest of my site. Thanks for your input though!